# Provide username and password for chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using Chef's windows cookbook to provision some windows servers.  Here's the recipe:

```
# Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET 4 - .NET Tools v4
windows_package "Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET 4 - .NET Tools v4" do
    source "\\\\MyServer\\MyDrive\\chef\\WinSDKNetFx40Tools_amd64\\WinSDK_nfx40tools_amd64.msi"
    installer_type :msi
    action :install
end
```

The problem is that I'm running into a permissions error when trying to access that UNC path.  Is it possible to provide a username/password to `windows_package` so I can tell it who to access the share as?  I've tried to store credentials via Credentials Manager, but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not allow credentials to be included directly in a UNC path. So there does not appear to be Chef support for authenticating while accessing files over UNC paths.

Chef's `mount` resource supports mounting a remote path. It allows passing username and password on Windows. So you could mount the UNC path before the `windows_package` call and then reference the mounted drive path instead of the UNC path.

Untested example:

```
mount "Z:" do
  action :mount
  device "\\\\MyServer\\MyDrive\\chef\\WinSDKNetFx40Tools_amd64\\"
  username "whoever"
  password "whatever"
end

windows_package "Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET 4 - .NET Tools v4" do
    source "Z:\\WinSDK_nfx40tools_amd64.msi"
    installer_type :msi
    action :install
end
```

Mount resource documentation:
http://docs.opscode.com/resource_mount.html

Mount resource source:
https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/807891d08dc5c436da237ec8a09639cea87a04fa/lib/chef/provider/mount/windows.rb#L60